# Exit for loop when a condition is met, for an array

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script.

- The script runs on multiple servers.
- It sends an email to the address mentioned in the TO field.
- There can be one of the 2 recipients of the mail (user1@domain.com or user2@domain.com), depending on the server on which the script is executing.
- There's a list of 4 pre-defined servers. If the script is executing on one of these servers, it sends the email to user1@domain.com. Else, it sends the email to user2@domain.com.

I thought this is correct, but I missed a logic that on every server both if and else condition will be checked.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname -s)
FILE_TEMP=/tmp/new.log
echo -e "This is a test from SERVER_NAME" >> $FILE_TEMP
subject="sending file from $SERVER_NAME"

Servers=(flipunix1 flipunix2 flipunix3 flipunix7)
for i in ${Servers[*]}
do
    if [ "$SERVER_NAME" == "$i" ];
    then
        to="user1@domain.com"
        echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME and i value is $i "
        break
    else
        to="user2@domain.com"
        echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME and i value is $i "
        break
    fi
done

also_to="user3@domain.com"
mail -s "$subject" "$to" "$also_to" < $FILE_TEMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname -s)
FILE_TEMP=/tmp/new.log
echo -e "This is a test from SERVER_NAME" >> $FILE_TEMP
subject="sending file from $SERVER_NAME"

Servers=(flipunix1 flipunix2 flipunix3 flipunix7)
for i in ${Servers[*]}
do
if [ "$SERVER_NAME" == "$i" ];
then
to="yugnesh@samil.com"
echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME and i value is $i "
break
fi
done

if [ -z "$to" ];
then
to="sanket@samil.com"
echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME "
fi

also_to="flipteam@samil.com"
mail -s "$subject" "$to" "$also_to" < $FILE_TEMP
```

or (a shorter version)

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname -s)
FILE_TEMP=/tmp/new.log
echo -e "This is a test from SERVER_NAME" >> $FILE_TEMP
subject="sending file from $SERVER_NAME"

Servers=(flipunix1 flipunix2 flipunix3 flipunix7)

if ! printf "%s\n" "${Servers[@]}" | grep -qw -m 1 "$SERVER_NAME";
then
to="sanket@samil.com"
else
to="yugnesh@samil.com"
fi

also_to="flipteam@samil.com"
mail -s "$subject" "$to" "$also_to" < $FILE_TEMP
```

Comment: if ! printf "%s\n" "${Servers[@]}" | grep -qw -m 1 "$SERVER_NAME";    thank you for the response. Could you help me understand the logic here? Would really help me in understand better.

Comment: Of course! First, I'm printing all the elements in the `Servers` array, putting them into separate lines (`printf "%s\n" "${Servers[@]}"`); with the `grep` command, we filter by the exact (`-w` option) first match (`-m 1`) and suppress the output to `stdout` (`-q`). The `if` statement is a stylized approach to running the command described above in a previous line and constructing the condition as `if [ $? != 0 ]; then`; it's just the syntax shellcheck recommended by the SC2181 standard. If you have any more questions, let me know!

Comment: The `-m 1` option isn't necessary since the `-q` causes the `grep` to exit immediately when a match is found.

Comment: @Rfroes87 thanks for the explanation, the latter one is beneficial to me. And as @M. Nejat Aydin suggested, I have removed `-m 1` and see no difference. Any recommendations on it?

Comment: @Rfroes87 I am also thinking, if I want to keep all the servers names in a file on same directory ( say servers_info.txt) , can i read them like below and same works? I am getting error currently .


`if ! echo -e servers_info.txt | grep -qw -m 1 "$SERVER_NAME";
then
to="sanket@samil.com"
else
to="yugnesh@samil.com"
fi`

Comment: @Erroruploading In that case, you must use `cat` instead of `echo -e`; or better yet, just start the expression with `grep` specifying the file like `grep -qw -m 1 "$SERVER_NAME" servers_info.txt; then to="sanket@samil.com" else to="yugnesh@samil.com" fi`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to send `to="yugnesh@samil.com"` if the `SERVER_NAME` is one within the `Servers` array, and if it isn't, you want to send `to="sanket@samil.com"`. If so, your loop logic sets `to="sanket@samil.com"` and breaks the loop every time `SERVER_NAME` does not match -- even if `SERVER_NAME` may match on the next iteration. You can remedy that by removing the `break`, e.g.

```
for i in ${Servers[*]}
do
    if [ "$SERVER_NAME" = "$i" ];
    then
        to="yugnesh@samil.com"
        echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME and i value is $i "
        break
    else
        to="sanket@samil.com"
    fi
done
```

Now `to="sanket@samil.com"` is set each time, but if the name is found in `SERVER_NAME` the loop exits with `to="yugnesh@samil.com"`. Only if there is no match doe the send remain `to="sanket@samil.com"`.

You can simply set `to="sanket@samil.com"` before the loop and do:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname -s)
FILE_TEMP=/tmp/new.log
echo -e "This is a test from SERVER_NAME" >> $FILE_TEMP
subject="sending file from $SERVER_NAME"
to="sanket@samil.com"

Servers=(flipunix1 flipunix2 flipunix3 flipunix7)
for i in ${Servers[*]}
do
    if [ "$SERVER_NAME" = "$i" ];
    then
        to="yugnesh@samil.com"
        echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME and i value is $i "
        break
    fi
done

also_to="flipteam@samil.com"
mail -s "$subject" "$to" "$also_to" < $FILE_TEMP
```

That will accomplish the same thing. (you can add an `if ... fi` and check `if [ "$to" = "sanket@samil.com" ]` if you want to output a message that that was used.)

You can also eliminate the loop entirely and simply use `[[ ... ]]` with the array contents and `SERVER_NAME`, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
SERVER_NAME=$(hostname -s)
FILE_TEMP=/tmp/new.log
echo -e "This is a test from SERVER_NAME" >> $FILE_TEMP
subject="sending file from $SERVER_NAME"
to="sanket@samil.com"

Servers=(flipunix1 flipunix2 flipunix3 flipunix7)

[[ ${Servers[@]} =~ $SERVER_NAME ]] && {
    to="yugnesh@samil.com"
    echo -e "server name picked is $SERVER_NAME "
}

also_to="flipteam@samil.com"
mail -s "$subject" "$to" "$also_to" < $FILE_TEMP
```

(same note on checking `if [ "$to" = "sanket@samil.com" ]` if you want to output something based on that being chosen)

Let me know if I didn't understand correctly.

(**note:** there is only one `=` to check string equality in `[...]`)

Comment: This is such a nice logic i missed it , surprisingly i used almost same logic few months ago on a script. But thank you, you showed the simplicity.

Comment: Sure, I gonna do that. I have still some doubts on the answers, once I have them,I will make sure to mark as answered.

Comment: Okay, that is fine. Generally a day or so is the normal active lifetime for a question. If you edit it will move it back active. Take as long as you like.